# Difference between struct and association

Tags: oop

I was asked 2,3 questions in an interview which didn't make any sense.

1. Difference between deadlock and thread ( i couldnt compare them )
2. Difference between struct and association ( not comparable again)

Are these even valid questions? If yes what would be the answer.

Comment: Strange questions. Esp. the first can only be answered by defining both.

Comment: Were they asking the difference between a struct and an associative array? That kind of depends on the language and the vernacular around those terms in that language's community. Struct means something very different to someone writing C than someone writing PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, these are unusual questions, but one could answer:

- [a **thread** (of execution) is the smallest unit of processing that can be scheduled by an operating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computer_science%29) and
- [A **deadlock** is a situation wherein two or more competing actions are each waiting for the other to finish, and thus neither ever does](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock).

or shorter: a **deadlock** is a situation that **thread** could be in. That's not really a difference...

I think if you can describe thread and deadlock that would be fine. It could be an intentionally misleading question so you must really sure what you know to tell the interviewer that there is no really difference, because one can't compare the tow *things*.

The same goes for struct and association.